# HTAccess different Redirect when logged in

Tags: php, database, .htaccess

Website URL: www.mgteurope.com

I have been tasked to transfer the site from one hosting to another.

Upon transferring the site, all has gone well and connected to the database.

**The problem**
When you click on the links down the left hand side, you should be directed to the pages, but only if you are logged in.

When you are not logged in, it should display 403 forbidden when you click the side links.

Users who are logged in, will be able to see the pages as full.

At the moment, when you click the pages, logged in or not logged in, you are given the template page displaying all data.

**HTAccess File**

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html

AddHandler x-httpd-php5  .htm .html

<Files .htaccess>

order allow,deny

deny from all

</Files>
```

Thank You and I will try to answer question to clarify but I am lost on this

Comment: that was the whole old .htaccess file? are you sure you're not missing parts?

Answer (score 0):

htaccess does not know if a user is logged in or not. You will need to make changes to the PHP code to achieve your goal.